# For each request return response in socket C#

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I want to create for each request return response in socket c# and android.
I find the relevant socket and send a request, asking for the data I need.
After sending the request, I receive bytes until it sends the response. Then I stop receiving.

My server will need to handle many clients at once, and preferably multiple requests from a client at once. I need both the client and server to be able to receive messages at any time

I wrote this code:

```
message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataRec,0,c);
            dataRec = new byte[2048];
            switch(message)
            {
                case "list-menu":
                    sendListMenu();
                    break;

                case "login":

                    isLogin(message);
                    break;
            }
```

login method

```
public void isLogin(string str){
          string message = "";
          Model_Users users;

         dataSend=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("send-result");
         newsocket.Send(dataSend);
         //newsocket.close(); if close not receive            
         c = newsocket.Receive(dataRec);
         message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataRec,0,c);

          XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model_Users));

              using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(message))
              {
                  if (reader != null)
                  {
                      users = (Model_Users)xml.Deserialize(reader);
                      MessageBox.Show(users.username);
                      dataSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("success-login");
                      newsocket.Send(dataSend);
                      newsocket.Close();
                  }

              }
          }
```

android code (client):

```
  socket = new Socket();
            socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ip")), 9999);
            socket.connect(socketAddress, 10000);
            bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            bufferWriter.write(getrequest);
            bufferWriter.flush();
            String rvdMsgTxt = "";
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while ((rvdMsgTxt = bufferedReader.readLine()).equals("success-login")) {
                stringBuilder.append(rvdMsgTxt);
                bufferedReader.mark(100);
                bufferedReader.reset();
            }

            bufferWriter.write(XMLConvertor.usersSerializeXML("user", "pass"));
            bufferWriter.flush();
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: when i send request get response but when i send request and get response and i want get next response there is an problem to get and send

Comment: for example :
'public void isLogin(string str){
         ///code
         socket.send(...);
        //error socket.close();
         socket.Receive(...);

          }'

Comment: this SOLVED by newsocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

Comment: just how to reopen socket when closed?

Answer (score 0):

this SOLVED by newsocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);